# SQL statement to get all patient with no appointment

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have a typical patient table and an Appointment table defined in such a way that I can do JOIN query as the following to return Appointment for all patients.

```
SELECT Patients.LastName, Patients.FirstName, Appointments.AppointmentNo
FROM Patients
INNER JOIN Appointments ON patients.id = Patients.patient_id
```

The question is, how do I write a statement that would return all Patients with NO Appointment?

Comment: Can you share structure of your SQL tables and some records in it

Comment: WHERE Appointments.AppointmentNo IS NULL 
Maybe
WHERE Appointments.AppointmentNo = 'No'
you can use where clause to

Comment: (As can  be expected,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various approaches to acheive your desired output

1. **Subquery**

   You can use subquery to fetch patient ids that do not exist in Appointments

> ```
> Select * from patients 
> where id not in (select distinct patient_id from Appointments)
> ```

2. **Left Join**

   You can use Left join to query records that do not join with appointments

> ```
> select patients.* from patients
> left join Appointments on patients.id= Appointments.patient_id
> where Appointments.patient_id is null
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT Patients.LastName, 
        Patients.FirstName,
       Appointments.AppointmentNo
 FROM Patients
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Appointments
 ON Patients.id= Appointments.patient_id
 Where Appointments.patient_id is null;
```